# Google Chrome missing icons and high CPU usage

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, icons, cpu-usage

- I recently found that icons in Google Chrome (EG next to tab names, and also in bookmarks bar), which were previously working fine, were not being rendered and instead showing the "Globe" icon
- I also noticed that Google Chrome was constantly consuming excessively high CPU usage (about 30-40%, driving my laptop fan crazy), even when I only had one tab open which was the "New tab page" (you'd think this would require ≈ 0 CPU usage at all)
- I think these 2 problems started simultaneously (although it's difficult to be 100% sure of this)
- I tried disabling unused extensions, and also uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome (on Windows 10), but the problem still persists
- Questions:

  - Are these 2 problems related (Google Chrome missing icons and high CPU usage)?
  - What is the root cause of these 2 issues?
  - How do I fix them?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue a couple of times right after Chrome updates. I don't know the real reason but high CPU usage most probably is related to the broken Favicons cache.

**How I fix it:**

1. Remove your current profile (click the avatar -> gear icon -> delete);
2. Close Chrome and (it's important!) kill its CPU-consuming process via Task Manager;
3. Open Chrome and re-create the profile by signing in again.

If your Sync setting was on, you will not miss anything and even will be able to restore all your open tabs through History.

**UPDATE**

Finally, I have discovered the true reason for the issue: VPN. While being connected to the Internet through VPN Chrome may unsuccessfully try to rebuild favicons cache. So it hangs causing a CPU-consuming process and showing placeholders instead of favicons.

The cure is much simpler than described above: just temporarily disconnect from VPN, close Chrome (and kill its hanging process), open it again, wait until favicons are ready, and connect to your VPN again.

Answer (score 0):

### How I fixed these problems

1. I uninstalled Google Chrome (just as I did before)
2. **I deleted the entire directory `"C:\Users\Jake\AppData\Local\Google"`**
3. I reinstalled Google Chrome

Now both problems are 100% fixed.

### Are these 2 problems related?

The fact that both problems started approximately simultaneously, and that one solution fixed both problems, are both consistent with the suggestion that the 2 problems were somehow related, although it could just be a coincidence.

### What is the root cause of these 2 issues?

- I don't have any concrete answers, but...
- CPU usage was high when Chrome was only showing a "New tab page", which shouldn't have been using very much CPU at all
- CPU usage issue **was not** fixed simply by uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome
- CPU usage issue **was** fixed when I also deleted `AppData\Local\Google` (after uninstalling and before reinstalling Chrome)
- There was no other apparent malfunction, besides high CPU usage and missing icons
- Unexpectedly high CPU usage that was fixed by deleting `AppData\Local\Google` is behaviour that would be consistent with the existence of some sort of malware that was living inside `AppData\Local\Google`, EG [cryptojacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptojacking) software, but it's difficult to be 100% sure

Comment: Only #2 was needed. And no, you're jumping to conclusions both for the two problems being related - there can be more than one problem in any given user profile that are totally unrelated and yet the "solution" of using a new fresh profile solves all user profile issues, related and unrelated. And the rest is pure speculation that now can't be tested, plausible but just one hypotheses among thousands.